# nginx : gzip: text/* seems not to compress text/javascript

Tags: nginx

Do I correctly understand, from experience, that mime types text/* is not supported on nginx?

Config was:

```
gzip_types
    text/css
    text/*
```

And javascript was not gzipped.

Went to

```
gzip_types
    text/css
    text/*
    text/javascript
```

and now javascript is gzipped.... (so I should drop text/* right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types):

> Enables gzipping of responses for the specified MIME types in addition
>   to “text/html”. The special value “*” matches any MIME type (0.8.29).
>   Responses with the “text/html” type are always compressed.

So the asterisk `*` does only work if it’s standing alone, not within a type.

So yes, yo can drop it.